# Arquivos de homologação para Produção

Tags: asp.net

Fiz uma alteração numa página asp.net em homologação. Quais arquivos das pastas em homologação tenho que mandar para o pessoal de infra subir essas alterações para a página em produção ?
PS:Compilei e mandei apenas os arquivos com a data e hora da compilação existentes na pasta bin e a aspx, mas não surtiu as alterações.

Comment: Tenta dar alguns F5

Comment: Ou Ctrl+F5. Pode ajudar.... Mas eu não tenho certeza se apenas isso resolve seu problema, pois como um a pagina acaba virando uma dll com nome qualquer (App_Web_obbv3t5i.dll por ex.) Pode ser que uma nova compilação gere uma dll diferente e seu projeto não a reconhece... O ideal é compilar todo o projeto.

Comment: Já fiz isso e nada. Mas são só esses arquivos mesmo ou tem mais algo ?

Comment: Mudou o ASPX também ? Se você mudou o ASPX (exemplo, colocou um texto a mais) e depois de atualizar não aparece esta alteração em tela, possivelmente seu TI não copiou para o lugar certo. A parte html do aspx não é compilada então deveria ter resultado imediato

Comment: Entendi, pensei que fosse isso também.